# Why Logrus writes logs to Linux logs?

Tags: go, logging

I use Logrus library to write my golang logs to file. The problem is that logrus also writes the logs to Linux system logs. Here is my log output in log configs.

```
log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
```

I do not want Logrus to write application logs to Linux system logs. Any idea about solving this problem?

Comment: Are you running this application as a service by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is running as a service. Does it cause that behavior?

Comment: If you start a process as service, its output will usually show up in syslog. Look at your distribution's syslog configuration manuals to suppress logs for a particular service.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I thought it is about my app config. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

To write output to file, you can set output to a file handler.

```golang
file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREATE, 0755)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
logrus.SetOutput(f)
```

In case you want to introduce more advanced logic to handle the output, you can use this library [Lumberjack](https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack) as log output